# Do mongo find queries perform faster with more criteria?

Tags: performance, mongodb, optimization, mongodb-query, query-performance

Does performance improve by limiting the find (or findOne) with more criteria?

An example:

```
db.users.find({_id : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111")})

db.users.find({_id : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111"), accountId : ObjectId("22222222222222222222222")})
```

Another example:

```
db.users.find({full_name: 'Lionel Messi'})

db.users.find({full_name : 'Lionel Messi', first_name : 'Lionel', last_name : 'Messi' })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, no. Because mongoDB tends to return a cursor of the first N values found, if you're being *more* specific, it will take longer to find values matching that criteria.

If you want to see what could be effecting the speed of your query, its a good idea to use the `explain()` method.

See here for more details: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/

Answer (score 1):

No since you are using `_id` which is unique.

As for making the query slower: it *could* be slower by nanoseconds at most if there is not a compound index on `{_id, accountId}` since once the documents by the `_id` index have been found they will be loaded into memory to match the `accountId` field.

MongoDB will find by index before looking at fields which are not witin the selected index.

However since your query (being uncovered) will load the document prior to returning anyway the only thing slowing the query down is that final match which is basically negliable in speed.

Comment: I see. Added a second example. Also curious about non-unique _id cases.

Comment: @Chandrew in that case: indeed, if the query hit a compound index i5t would be faster than not and only searching by `full_name` due to time saved loading the results of multiples of documents

Answer (score 0):

In this case no. `_id` is indexed automatically and it uniquely identifies documents. The first criteria

```
{_id : ObjectId("111111111111111111111111")}
```

will find the document using the index. Checking the value of `accountId` will actually make the query slower because MongoDB has to check an other value.